# Algorithm to dynamically populate Javascript array with zeros before and after values

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, django

I get a data of months dynamically with python/django and pass it to my template. There I use Javascript to manipulate the data

That means that in my template I have a javascript array, each number representing a month like so:

`months = [1,2,3,4]`

or so:

`months = [4,5,6]`

or so:

`months = [6,7,8]`

Depending on the array above I'd like to populate the missing positions with zeros. Missing positions means that the array should have a length of 12 at the end. Each month should be at the accurate position. For example:

`months = [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

or so

`months = [0,0,0,4,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

or so

`months = [0,0,0,0,0,6,7,8,0,0,0,0]`

I tried many things. `Splicing` seemed a good method but didn't work as expected. I couldn't solve it using `Array.fill`. I also tried to create a new array with 12 zeros and then pushing the values of the other array into it, but it didn't work.

Can somebody point me into the right direction or has an idea? Very much appreciated.

Comment: **it didn't work** - Post the code that didn't work along with the error/unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may map empty array of 12 items, checking if month number is present within your source array:

```js
const padZeroes =  arr => [...Array(12)].map((item,index) => arr.includes(index+1) ? index+1 : 0);

console.log(padZeroes([5,6,7,8]));
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because I ended up using it and it is just one line of code. Thanks to everyone who shared their ideas though!

Answer (score 6):

You could take a new array and fill it with the items on the index, if found or with zero.

```js
const fill = m => Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, i) => +m.includes(i + 1) && i + 1);

console.log(...fill([1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(...fill([4, 5, 6]));
console.log(...fill([6, 7, 8]));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Make a list of the 12 months

`true_months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]` (or `true_months = list(range(1,13))`)

then your variable

`months = [4,5,6]`

and by a simple if/else in a for

`[x if x in months else 0 for x in true_months]`

will return

`[0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! It works perfectly!